# Iframe is not working for www.example.com/my-account

Tags: iframe

Iframe is working fine for www.example.com, But its not working for www.example.com/my-account

I followed few tricks, Like: adding these codes:

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

But still, it's showing the same error.
Is there any proper solution in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that your web page is https (like: https://www.example.com/my-account) and the iframe was loaded via http. Try loading your web page in this way:

```
http://www.example.com/my-account
```

If the page is http, the iframe content must be http. That's why, you have to remove "s" from "https."